# NET Framework to .NET Core 3.1 - ResourceDictionary in external library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

i'm trying to convert my application wpf application from .net framework 4.8 to .net core.
I have a a class library .net core 3.1, where i put all my themes, styles, languages and other resources, when i try to run it breaks because itcan't find my resource

IOException: Cannot locate resource 'windows/vulpesaccesswindow.xaml'.

in my app.xaml i have this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Diagrams.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Diagrams.Extensions.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GanttView.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Pivot.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.PivotFieldList.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.VisualStudio2013;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.ScheduleView.xaml" />
            <!--TELERIK-->
            <!--UIX-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Windows/VulpesAccessWindow.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Windows/VulpesShellWindow.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Windows/VulpesDialogWindow.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Resources/ThemeLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Resources/BaseColors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Resources/VulpesTelerik.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Resources/Labels.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Resources/Navigation.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Resources/Validation.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UIX;component/Resources/Templates.xaml" />

            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:ShellBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

i try to set my resource VulpesAccessWindow.xaml Build Action to Resource and Embedded Resource, but nothing, when i run it breaks..

Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using the full pack notation works in a solution I have:

```
 <ResourceDictionary  Source="pack://application:,,,/UILib;component/Resources/FontResources.xaml"/>
```

In the library, this is Build Action Page.

[image]